# Venn diagram not getting rendered in highcharter package

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I am trying to emulate [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/venn-diagram/) venn diagram from highcharts API using [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/vignettes/replicating-highcharts-demos.html) as a guide.

Following is the code I am writing in R:

```
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>% 
  hc_series(
    list(
      type = "venn",
      name = "Venn Diagram",
      data = list(
        list(sets = c("Good"), value = 2),
        list(sets = c("Fast"), value = 2),
        list(sets = c("Good", "Fast"), value = 1)
      )
    )
  )
```

When I run this code, nothing gets rendered.

What am I missing in this code?

Answer (score 0):

The sets argument should be a list object. `c("good")` is a character object.

Try this.

```
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>% 
    hc_series(
        list(
            type = "venn",
            name = "Venn Diagram",
            data = list(
                list(sets = list("Good"), value = 2),
                list(sets = list("Fast"), value = 2),
                list(sets = list("Good", "Fast"), value = 1)
            )
        )
    )
```